# Rename files based on list

Tags: bash, rename, mv

I have these video files;

```
Fringe.S03E01.mkv 
Fringe.S03E02.mkv 
Fringe.S03E03.mkv 
etc...
```

I also have a .csv text file of the episode's titles;

```
01,Olivia
02,The Box
03,The Plateau
etc...
```

what I am trying to get to is;

```
Fringe.S03E01.Olivia.mkv
Fringe.S03E02.The Box.mkv
Fringe.S03E03.The Plateau.mkv
etc...
```

Ive been trying to figure out the syntax for a bash script using foreach, but not getting any useable results..

Comment: "I have a list" -- In what format? Is this a file or an array or ...?;

Comment: the files are just video files, the titles are a plain text file

Comment: Hello @user88710. you have spaces between The and box ? The and Plateau?

Comment: No surprise - `foreach` is not a `bash` command.

Comment: To anyone reading this question: there was no mention of ".csv text file" in the original OP's. That is just a sample of flagrant edit abuse by privileged users. Keep that in mind before wondering why the answers don't handle an actual [csv file](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180), with quoting, double quoting, CRLF, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fringe_copy(){
        local IFS=,
        while read num title; do
                f=Fringe.S03E$num.mkv
                if [ -f "$f" ]; then
                        echo mv "$f" "${f%.mkv}.$title.mkv"
                fi
        done
}
fringe_copy <list_of_files
```

You'll have to remove the `echo` from before `mv` if you're satisfied with the dry run.

Comment: awesome awesome, thank you mosvy!!  I understand most of what you're doing here except for the "${f%.mkv}"....

Comment: @user88710 It just strips the `.mkv` extension. Look [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dash.1.html), search for "Remove Smallest Suffix Pattern".

Answer (score 1):

Try also this `awk` proposal

```
ls Fringe* |
awk '
NR == FNR       {EP[$1]=$2
                 next
                }
                {IX=substr($2, length($2)-1, 2)
                 $2 = $2 OFS EP[IX]
                }
1
' FS=, episodes.csv FS=. OFS=. -
Fringe.S03E01.Olivia.mkv
Fringe.S03E02.The Box.mkv
Fringe.S03E03.The Plateau.mkv
```

After having read the episode titles file into the replacement array, it acts upon the `ls` results and inserts the respective title based on the number in the last two chars of $2.